# How to run a Docker image from a Java program?

Tags: java, docker

That's what I would do in the command line:

```
$ docker run -i imagename mycommand
```

Should I just use `Runtime.getRuntime().exe()`? Should I use one of the [available Java APIs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/remote_api_client_libraries/)?

From what I've seen, the APIs would help me to pull and push images, but all I want is to run a particular command on a particular public image, and I don't seem to find an easy way to do that with the APIs.

---

I'm attaching the actual command I'd be executing, just in case:

```
$ docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -port 8080
```

Comment: If it does what you need simply execute the command with exec. Sometimes the simple solution is the best solution, don`t search for a too complicated solution ...

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'm still trying to make sure I'm not losing any significant benefits from the API, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should think to use java api to manage docker images/container.

You can start with any of them

```
Java    docker-java https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java  Active
Java    docker-client   https://github.com/spotify/docker-client    Active
```

Refer:

[Docker Remote API client libraries](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/remote_api_client_libraries/)